# Extract each library into its own file

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

By default, vue-cli extracts all modules found in `node_modules` into a single file, vendor.js. Here's the plugin code

```
    // keep module.id stable when vender modules does not change
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        minChunks: function(module, count) {
            // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
            return (
                module.resource &&
                /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
                module.resource.indexOf(
                    path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
                ) === 0
            )
        }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'manifest',
        chunks: ['vendor']
    }),
```

I'd like to give each library their own file. Reason being that i'm trying to get a twitch extension approved, and they are very strict on "obfuscated code". Someone told me that it would be helpful to the review process if each library was in it's own file.

So if i'm using vue, vue-router, and vuex. I would like to go from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/vendor.27baea56fa1d6f323c7b.js"></script>
```

To this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/vue.27baea56fa1d6f323c7b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/vue-router.27baea56fa1d6f323c7b.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/vuex.27baea56fa1d6f323c7b.js"></script>
```

I would provide my attempt at a solution but webpack is still sort of a mystery to me. Thanks.